# Workaround that allows the use of digits as part of counter names?

Tags: macros, counters

I tried to define indexed counters, such as x1, x2, . . . etc, by defining them like this : \newcount\x1, \newcount\x2, . . . etc, but it didn't work. Is there a workaround for this in TeX or LaTeX ?   I have written a small tex-file that illustrates what happens when you try it. Note added : With the remark made by @cfr, that in LaTex one may use the command \newcounter{name} the question has a good answer that cannot easily be found by using the search engine. (I have some good reference books for TeX, but not for LaTeX.)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Example tex-file that illustrates what happens  %%
%%  when you use a number in the name of a counter  %%
%%                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%         

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=0.75in, paperheight=1.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\newcount\a  \newcount\b \newcount\c7

\a=1   \b=41 \c7=78

\noindent
a = \number\a  
\par \vskip 5pt \noindent
b = \number\b  
\par \vskip 5pt \noindent 
c7 = \number\c7 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are using LaTeX, wouldn't it be better to use e.g. `\newcounter` rather than `\newcount`?

Comment: @cfr then you could use digits:-) `\newcounter{a1}` is OK:-)

Comment: I didn't know there was a variant. But that would indeed be the workaround. Thanks !  With the new answer it isn't a duplicate after all, then ?

Comment: @user35145 It should be reworded to specifically mention counters, at least

Comment: I extended my answer with specifics about counters as the question is reopened.

Answer (score 4):

tex parsing is controlled by "catcodes" (`\catcode`) the catcode of any character is changeable, but control sequence names can be any number of catcode 11 characters (letters)  or a single non-letter so `\"o` for example is `\"{o}` not a command called `"o` digits are non-letters so you can have `\1` but not `\a1`.  It is possible to make digits letters by making them catcode 11, but many things will break so it's not a good idea except in very controlled environments.

Note that this restriction just applies to parsing of a name after the escape character (normally `\`).

```
\csname name with 1 and 2\endcsname
```

accesses the command with name `name with 1 and 2` which has digits and spaces in its name, you just can't access it via `\name with 1 and 2`.  In particular latex has some constructs such as environments that are always accessed via name so `\begin{tabular*}` internally uses the macro with name `tabular*` even though that may not be accessed via `\tabular*`. LaTeX counters though have a mixed design, they are allocated by name, so you can perhaps go

```
\newcounter{c7}
```

but they are used via command tokens; in particular the above creates a command with name `thec7` that expands to the print form of the counter, but this can not be accessed via `\thec7` but only via `\csname thec7\endcsname` so it is best to avoid such constructs and only use counter names that generate legal command names (that is, just consists of letters).